# Что является причиной коммуникативной ошибки?

Tags: коммуникативные-требования

В сочинении ученика употреблена следующая фраза: "Мы читали описание фашистских зверств Ильи Эренбурга". Предложение, видимо, должно вызывать комический эффект. Помогите "диагностировать" и исправить!

Answer (score 4):

**Мы читали описание фашистских зверств в книге Ильи Эренбурга.**

В приведенном предложении "зверства" можно отнести к самому Эренбургу, правда, комическим этот эффект трудно назвать.

Или по-другому: *Мы читали рассказ о  фашистских зверствах в книге Ильи Эренбурга*.
Описание зверств — не лучшее сочетание, если это художественная книга, эмоциональный фон у слов разный.

Comment: Вы увлеклись, — вопрос касается закавыченного.

Comment: @shampar Вам что-то показалось лишним в ответе?

Comment: Всё в порядке. Показалось. Исправленный текст не отличить от диагноза.

Answer (score 3):

Причиной является *невнимательность* автора, а именно не замеченное им сочетание "**зверств Ильи Эренбурга**", которое придаёт предложению *недопустимую* двусмысленность, при том что не вызывает сомнений, какой из двух смыслов пытался выразить автор.

В *грамматическом* отношении возникновению этого сочетания способствовал падеж, в котором упомянут автор: родительный падеж в сочетании с "описанием" (*описание чего, кого*) прежде всего указывает на *предмет* описания, на автора же логичнее указывать в творительном падеже (*описание кем*), а с родительным падежом возможна конструкция "*в описании* такого-то автора".

Простейшим исправлением было бы добавление предлога "**у**" перед именем писателя (хотя можно увидеть нежелательные смыслы и в этом варианте). Можно было бы изменить и порядок слов (У Ильи Эренбурга мы читали описание...), но способы оптимизации этого предложения зависят от более общего контекста.